"Could NOT find OpenSSL" CMake error with "iOS Simulator" configuration
I have a C++ app that uses OpenSSL for calculating MD5 and SHA hashes:
#include <openssl/md5.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>

namespace crypto
{
    // A helper class that accepts OpennSLL functions as a template arguments.
    template <unsigned char * (*func)(const unsigned char *, size_t, unsigned char *), size_t N>
    class OpenSslHash;

    class OpenSslHash : public BasicHash<N>
    using Md5 = OpenSslHash<MD5, MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH>;
    using Sha1 = OpenSslHash<SHA1, SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH>;
    using Sha256 = OpenSslHash<SHA256, SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH>;
    using Sha512 = OpenSslHash<SHA512, SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH>;
}

In my CMake I find OpenSSL:
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED Crypto SSL)

I was able to build the app for MacOS Desktop configuration, but when I tried to run CMake for iOS Simulator I got the following error:
[cmake] CMake Error at /opt/local/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
[cmake]   Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the
[cmake]   system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY
[cmake]   OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR Crypto SSL)
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   /opt/local/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:600 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
[cmake]   /opt/local/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindOpenSSL.cmake:686 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
[cmake]   CMakeLists.txt:42 (find_package)

below I provided full CMake output:
    cmake] Running /opt/local/bin/cmake -S /Users/admin/dev/repos/tradeclient/src/TradeClient -B /Users/admin/dev/build/tcm -DCMAKE_GENERATOR:STRING=Xcode -DCMAKE_PROJECT_INCLUDE_BEFORE:FILEPATH=/Users/admin/dev/build/tcm/.qtc/package-manager/auto-setup.cmake -DQT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=/Users/admin/dev/libs/QT6/release/iOS/bin/qmake6 -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH:PATH=/Users/admin/dev/libs/QT6/release/iOS -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE:FILEPATH=/Users/admin/dev/libs/QT6/release/iOS/lib/cmake/Qt6/qt.toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES:STRING=x86_64 -DCMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT:STRING=iphonesimulator -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_INIT:STRING= in /Users/admin/dev/build/tcm.
    [cmake] -- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 15.0.0.15000309
    [cmake] -- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 15.0.0.15000309
    [cmake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
    [cmake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
    [cmake] -- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang - skipped
    [cmake] -- Detecting C compile features
    [cmake] -- Detecting C compile features - done
    [cmake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
    [cmake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
    [cmake] -- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ - skipped
    [cmake] -- Detecting CXX compile features
    [cmake] -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
    [cmake] -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
    [cmake] -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Success
    [cmake] -- Found Threads: TRUE
    [cmake] -- Found ZLIB: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator17.4.sdk/usr/lib/libz.tbd (found version "1.2.12")
    [cmake] -- Found WrapSystemZLIB: TRUE
    [cmake] -- Using system ZLIB.
    [cmake] -- Found WrapZLIB: TRUE
    [cmake] -- Performing Test HAVE_STDATOMIC
    [cmake] -- Performing Test HAVE_STDATOMIC - Success
    [cmake] -- Found WrapAtomic: TRUE
    [cmake] -- Looking for backtrace
    [cmake] -- Looking for backtrace - found
    [cmake] -- backtrace facility detected in default set of libraries
    [cmake] -- Found Backtrace: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator17.4.sdk/usr/include
    [cmake] -- Using Qt bundled PCRE2.
    [cmake] -- Found WrapPCRE2: TRUE
    [cmake] -- Performing Test HAVE_GETTIME
    [cmake] -- Performing Test HAVE_GETTIME - Success
    [cmake] -- Performing Test HAVE_SHM_OPEN_SHM_UNLINK
    [cmake] -- Performing Test HAVE_SHM_OPEN_SHM_UNLINK - Success
    [cmake] -- Found WrapRt: TRUE
    [cmake] -- Performing Test HAVE_EGL
    [cmake] -- Performing Test HAVE_EGL - Failed
    [cmake] -- Could NOT find EGL (missing: EGL_INCLUDE_DIR HAVE_EGL EGL_LIBRARY) 
    [cmake] -- Performing Test HAVE_GLESv2
    [cmake] -- Performing Test HAVE_GLESv2 - Success
    [cmake] -- Found GLESv2: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator17.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework
    [cmake] -- Using Qt bundled PNG.
    [cmake] -- Found WrapPNG: TRUE
    [cmake] -- Using Qt bundled Harfbuzz.
    [cmake] -- Found WrapHarfbuzz: TRUE
    [cmake] -- Using Qt bundled Freetype.
    [cmake] -- Found WrapFreetype: TRUE
    [cmake] -- Using Qt bundled Jpeg.
    [cmake] -- Found WrapJpeg: TRUE
    [cmake] -- Found AVFoundation: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator17.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework
    [cmake] CMake Error at /opt/local/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
    [cmake]   Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the
    [cmake]   system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY
    [cmake]   OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR Crypto SSL)
    [cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
    [cmake]   /opt/local/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:600 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
    [cmake]   /opt/local/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindOpenSSL.cmake:686 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
    [cmake]   CMakeLists.txt:42 (find_package)
    [cmake] 
    [cmake] 
    [cmake] -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    [cmake] 
    [cmake] The command "/opt/local/bin/cmake -S /Users/admin/dev/repos/tradeclient/src/TradeClient -B /Users/admin/dev/build/tcm -DCMAKE_GENERATOR:STRING=Xcode -DCMAKE_PROJECT_INCLUDE_BEFORE:FILEPATH=/Users/admin/dev/build/tcm/.qtc/package-manager/auto-setup.cmake -DQT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=/Users/admin/dev/libs/QT6/release/iOS/bin/qmake6 -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH:PATH=/Users/admin/dev/libs/QT6/release/iOS -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE:FILEPATH=/Users/admin/dev/libs/QT6/release/iOS/lib/cmake/Qt6/qt.toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES:STRING=x86_64 -DCMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT:STRING=iphonesimulator -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_INIT:STRING=" terminated with exit code 1.
    [cmake] 
    [cmake] Elapsed time: 00:19.

I have openssl installed probably because I am able to run openssl command from the terminal and there is /opt/local/include/openssl on my MacOS machine, but OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR variable is not defined.
Below I provided successful CMake output for MacOS Desktop:
[cmake] Running /opt/local/bin/cmake -S /Users/admin/dev/repos/tradeclient/src/TradeClient -B /Users/admin/dev/build/tcd -DCMAKE_GENERATOR:STRING=Xcode -DCMAKE_PROJECT_INCLUDE_BEFORE:FILEPATH=/Users/admin/dev/build/tcd/.qtc/package-manager/auto-setup.cmake -DQT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=/Users/admin/dev/libs/QT6/release/MacOs/bin/qmake6 -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH:PATH=/Users/admin/dev/libs/QT6/release/MacOs -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_INIT:STRING= in /Users/admin/dev/build/tcd.
[cmake] -- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 15.0.0.15000309
[cmake] -- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 15.0.0.15000309
[cmake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
[cmake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
[cmake] -- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang - skipped
[cmake] -- Detecting C compile features
[cmake] -- Detecting C compile features - done
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
[cmake] -- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ - skipped
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compile features
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
[cmake] -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
[cmake] -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Success
[cmake] -- Found Threads: TRUE
[cmake] -- Found ZLIB: /opt/local/lib/libz.dylib (found version "1.3.1")
[cmake] -- Found WrapSystemZLIB: TRUE
[cmake] -- Using system ZLIB.
[cmake] -- Found WrapZLIB: TRUE
[cmake] -- Performing Test HAVE_STDATOMIC
[cmake] -- Performing Test HAVE_STDATOMIC - Success
[cmake] -- Found WrapAtomic: TRUE
[cmake] -- Looking for backtrace
[cmake] -- Looking for backtrace - found
[cmake] -- backtrace facility detected in default set of libraries
[cmake] -- Found Backtrace: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX14.4.sdk/usr/include
[cmake] -- Using Qt bundled PCRE2.
[cmake] -- Found WrapPCRE2: TRUE
[cmake] -- Performing Test HAVE_GETTIME
[cmake] -- Performing Test HAVE_GETTIME - Success
[cmake] -- Performing Test HAVE_SHM_OPEN_SHM_UNLINK
[cmake] -- Performing Test HAVE_SHM_OPEN_SHM_UNLINK - Success
[cmake] -- Found WrapRt: TRUE
[cmake] -- Found OpenGL: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework
[cmake] -- Found WrapOpenGL: TRUE
[cmake] -- Using Qt bundled PNG.
[cmake] -- Found WrapPNG: TRUE
[cmake] -- Using Qt bundled Harfbuzz.
[cmake] -- Found WrapHarfbuzz: TRUE
[cmake] -- Using Qt bundled Freetype.
[cmake] -- Found WrapFreetype: TRUE
[cmake] -- Using Qt bundled Jpeg.
[cmake] -- Found WrapJpeg: TRUE
[cmake] -- Performing Test HAVE_LIBRESOLV_FUNCTIONS
[cmake] -- Performing Test HAVE_LIBRESOLV_FUNCTIONS - Success
[cmake] -- Found WrapResolv: TRUE
[cmake] -- Found GSSAPI: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/GSS.framework
[cmake] -- Found AVFoundation: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework
[cmake] -- Found OpenSSL: /opt/local/lib/libcrypto.dylib (found version "3.2.1") found components: Crypto SSL
[cmake] OpenSSL include: /opt/local/include
[cmake] Enabling 128 bit integer support.
[cmake] Using home made implementation of std::jthread.
[cmake] CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION: 23.4.0
[cmake] Posix native platform.
[cmake] AWL_PLATFORM_DIR: ../../lib/Awl/Platforms/Posix
[cmake] Applying the workaround for QT Creator.
[cmake] Detected locale "C" with character encoding "US-ASCII", which is not UTF-8.
[cmake] Qt depends on a UTF-8 locale, and has switched to "UTF-8" instead.
[cmake] If this causes problems, reconfigure your locale. See the locale(1) manual
[cmake] for more information.
[cmake] -- Configuring done (16.7s)
[cmake] -- Generating done (0.0s)
[cmake] -- Build files have been written to: /Users/admin/dev/build/tcd
[cmake] 
[cmake] Elapsed time: 00:17.

How to make my C++ code compile for iOS?

For your MacOS build how did you install your OpenSSL package?

@jpr42 I did not install it, I do not know where is it came from, probably it appeared with I installed some other packages.
